# MSE vs correlation in Data Science

Tags: machine-learning, correlation

This is just a general question. In Machine Learning, when you are training an algorithm, it is common to split up the dataset into a training and testing set, and then evaluating the accuracy of the model by calculating the MSE on the test set against the predictions made by the model. I was wondering if you were to compute the correlation coefficient instead, what would be the advantages/disadvantages of this approach? I have seen the correlation coefficient called a pseudo-R^2 or a type of R^2 as a measure of similarity between the test observations and the predicted observations in quite a few places online and in my stats lectures, so, I was just wondering what everyone's thoughts were on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSE is just one measure of the forecast performance. You can substitute or complement it with any number of other measures. For instance, if you're forecasting a sequence of values instead of the scalar, you could use the Kendal Tau correlation to measure how well your forecast predicts the shape of the curve.